# I bought a disc from a different region and if I do buy a digital version will all my saved data be accessible?

Tags: ps4, rainbow-six-siege

I was given rainbow six siege on disc as a present from America and when I wanted to purchase some r6 coins I couldn't because my disc was from a completely different region.

So I had the idea of buying rainbow six siege on ps4 store (digital version), in order to access the store content. However, will I be able to access my saved data if I start playing the digital version?

- Rainbow six siege disc version (Hawaii)
- Rainbow six siege digital version (Aus)

Answer (score 0):

If their the same PS4 account theoretically it shouldn't matter which copy you use. I would attempt to get in contact with Ubisoft support and ask.

Answer (score 0):

Digital and disc copies of the same game should not matter to the PSN Store or your saves. However different region versions of games (even if its the same title) may be identified by the PS4 as different games and you shouldn't expect that your saves would work.

Your best bet would be to borrow or rent a local version of the game and see what happens before buying the full digital copy.